# apache2 is showing my webpage directory and folders after installing ssl self-signed certificate.

Tags: ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

after configuring apache2 on my lamp, all content on my local webpage shows just directory and folders. It was working fine when I had it on http. I have been trying to figure when went wrong for hours. please help.

Comment: can you post your website configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you added a new VirtualHost on your existing apache configuration?

In this case, you should check the content of that section and ensure the index and the php handling are setup correctly (this depends on how you're using php, mod_php or fastcgi ecc). you can compare the http config with the new VirtualHost.